# Sendmail set domain in From field

Tags: email, sendmail

I am using a Hetzner root server running Debian 7. My IP address is 148.251.181.168.

My hosts file has the domain name immediately after 127.0.0.1, which was suggested as a solution elsewhere.

`127.0.0.1 lottoresults.ie`

/etc/mail/local-host-names has the following:

```
localhost
lottoresults.ie
```

I also have a reverse DNS entry in the Hetzner robot as specified on http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/DNS-Reverse-DNS/en

Despite this, when I send mails, using for example `mail -s "blah" my-address@gmail.com`, when I receive the email the from field is always root@static.168.181.251.148.clients.your-server.de**.

How can I set it so that it is From root@**lottoresults.ie**?

Comment: http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/DNS-Reverse-DNS/en

Comment: Thanks, I have added a reverse DNS entry as per above, but no difference (same problem).

Comment: You should update your question, then. You also will probably [need to disclose](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) your server's public IP address.

Comment: I don't see your IP address?

Comment: Your reverse DNS looks correct. You'll probably just have to wait for the TTL to expire (1-2 days).

Comment: OK, hopefully that should be it. Will wait further and see. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer was not to do what was in the comments, but rather the following.

Hetzner servers attempt first to send mail over IPv6 if possible, so I needed to:

- add an AAAA forward record
- edit Hetzner robot to add a reverse IPv6 record.

  Also make sure your hostname matches the domain you want. So:
- edit /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts
- invoke-rc.d hostname.sh start
- invoke-rc.d networking force-reload